# paypal adaptive payments-sdk showing error 540031 in website

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am using PayPal adaptive payments SDK with with payment detail api but it's showing me error like

```
[error] => Array 
( 
  [0] => ErrorData Object ( 
              [errorId] => 540031 
              [domain] => PLATFORM 
              [subdomain] => Application 
              [severity] => Error 
              [category] => Application 
              [message] => You do not have permission to get these payment details 
              [exceptionId] => [parameter] => 
              )
)
```

I think it gives me some permission error I have checked in my papal account for permission but still not getting the exact response and how to solve it. Please guide me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you asking for when this error message comes?

Comment: when i try to get payment detail at that time.

Comment: refer this http://tiku.io/questions/1752737/paypal-adaptive-payment-540031-error

Comment: i have set it as sandbox and same code is working separately but when i use it in my project it's stop working.

Answer (score 0):

I got solution...

Issue is with Paypal sandbox detail which i have entered in my configuration file.

I have change that it's working.

Thanks For support.